# Can you install command-line packages in jib docker image?

Tags: docker, maven, curl, jq, jib

I need to install command line tools like jq, curl etc in the docker image created by maven jib plugin. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can add all cli tools. Can you add the Dockerfile

Comment: @nischaygoyal That is what I am looking, how to get the Dockerfile that the maven jib plugin is using, then I can add layers.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the other answer, using a base image customized with pre-installed tools that rarely change is a good solution.

Alternatively, you may put `curl` using Jib's `<extraDirectories>` feature, which enables adding arbitrary files to the target image. Check the [Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) and [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) docs for more details. As explained in the docs, you will also need to configure `<permissions>` to set executable bits to `curl`.

If you prefer, you could even set up your Maven or Gradle builds to download `curl` and unpack it. Here's an [example Jib setup](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/examples/java-agent) (showing both Maven and Gradle) from the Jib repository.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a reference `Dockerfile` and you can build your own base image by creating your Dockerfile and then build it.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash procps

# Downloading and installing Maven
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.1
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=b4880fb7a3d81edd190a029440cdf17f308621af68475a4fe976296e71ff4a4b546dd6d8a58aaafba334d309cc11e638c52808a4b0e818fc0fd544226d952544
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && echo "Downlaoding maven" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  \
  && echo "Checking download hash" \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  \
  && echo "Unziping maven" \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# Downloading and installing Gradle
# 1- Define a constant with the version of gradle you want to install
ARG GRADLE_VERSION=4.0.1

# 2- Define the URL where gradle can be downloaded from
ARG GRADLE_BASE_URL=https://services.gradle.org/distributions

# 3- Define the SHA key to validate the gradle download
#    obtained from here https://gradle.org/release-checksums/
ARG GRADLE_SHA=d717e46200d1359893f891dab047fdab98784143ac76861b53c50dbd03b44fd4

# 4- Create the directories, download gradle, validate the download, install it, remove downloaded file and set links
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/gradle /usr/share/gradle/ref \
  && echo "Downlaoding gradle hash" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/gradle.zip ${GRADLE_BASE_URL}/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip \
  \
  && echo "Checking download hash" \
  && echo "${GRADLE_SHA}  /tmp/gradle.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
  \
  && echo "Unziping gradle" \
  && unzip -d /usr/share/gradle /tmp/gradle.zip \
   \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/gradle.zip \
  && ln -s /usr/share/gradle/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION} /usr/bin/gradle

# 5- Define environmental variables required by gradle
ENV GRADLE_VERSION 4.0.1
ENV GRADLE_HOME /usr/bin/gradle
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME /cache

ENV PATH $PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin

VOLUME $GRADLE_USER_HOME

CMD [""]
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Once your custom image is ready, push it to Registry and then reference it in `jib` in following manner.

```
mvn compile jib:build \
    -Djib.from.image=customImage
```

Comment: Ok, so jib docker image is a distroless image, that means there is no shell, and you won't be able to install anything.